# WooCommerce skipping down to reviews after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Please take a look at this web page:

http://www.riversidelifestyle.co.uk/index.php/product/lavender-body-scrub

It's a WordPress site running WooCommerce.

You'll notice that when the page finishes loading, "#tab-reviews" is added to the URL and the page skips down to the reviews section. I have been asked to debug this for a client but I've so far drawn a blank whilst I wait to be able to set-up a demo site to debug properly.

Has anyone seen this issue before, or can anyone tell from looking what the problem might be?

Thanks.

Comment: That's just strange. Chrome dev tools not able to capture anything for you? Seems like there is something performing a redirect on the window.  Hard to diagnose with out the code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There's a JS error in dev tools, but I disabled the plugin that causes it and the error was still there. Waiting for full site access so that I can create a dev site, then I'll go through disabling each plugin to see if I can narrow it down. I'll check to see if there's anything causing redirects - thanks.